# Angular - document.ready() issue, Jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How to test (using Jasmine) Angular code encapsulated inside `$(function(){...})` without breaking/halting in any way already working angular app?
I have such a situation, when each module is defined like this:

```
$(function(){
  angular.module('templates', ['commons']) 
  ...
})
```

And I want to test it.

Comment: They are both mine. I do not think it is a duplicate because I want all of my blocks `$(function(){...})` to remain and test in such a state if it is possible. I have found though a better solution: just to remove all of the `$(function(){...})`, then reorder my javascript imports, and only then test it, but still, is it actually possible to test WITH all of the `$(function(){...})` or it is not? Just curiosity.

Comment: Have you tried also wrapping your test code in a document ready block?

Comment: Yep, tried it and the tests themselves stop being invoked, the `it` part.